Maximal ideals of polynomial ring over rational numbers
Problem: Let $R$ be the polynomial ring over $\mathbb{Q}$ without unity. For $H < (\mathbb{Q}, +)$ we have that $I(H) := Hx + Rx$ is an ideal of $R$. I want to show that $I(H)$ is not contained in any maximal ideal of $R$, if $H \subsetneq \mathbb{Q}$ .
My attempt:
The quotient ring
\begin{align}
    \frac{R}{I(H)} = \{0 + I(H), qx + I(H) | q \notin H\} 
   \end{align}
has the trivial ideals $\{0\}$ and $R/I$. Furthermore, any
\begin{align}
    J/I(H) = \{0 + I(H), qx + I(H) | q \in U \leq \mathbb{Q}-H\}
   \end{align}
is an ideal, since $x^2 = 0 + I(H)$. Thus (by the lattice theorem)
\begin{align}
    I(H) \subseteq Ux + I(H) =: M
   \end{align}
But this set is not maximal. Suppose it is, then, for $K = \mathbb{Q} - (U \cup H)$ we have
\begin{align}
    Kx + Ux + I(H) = R
   \end{align}
Thats where I'm stuck. I want to show by contradiction that this is not maximal. I know of a similar argument to show that $(\mathbb{Q}, +, *)$ has no maximal ideal because $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ doesn't have a maximal proper subgroup. Can I use that somehow?

So we have $R=x \cdot \mathbb{Q}[x]$ (one variable)? If so, do you know the maximal ideals here?

@MartinBrandenburg Thanks for the response. Well it shouldn't have any maximal ideals. It should be easier to not use factor groups for this proof.
